# how to build electron app with vue cli 3?

Tags: vue.js, electron, electron-builder

Im building my first electron app and I want to use VueJs, I have installed vue via the cli3.

When i run the app in dev its all fine, however in production (after running a build) there is a warning in the console that vue builds are designed to run over an http-server. This is usually fine since it will be, however to embed vue in an electron app, I wont be using an http-server to serve the vue app.

the net effect of this is that when i build my electron app and run it, I just see a blank screen and none of the js/css/img files get loaded (all 404).

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

I reviewed so many vue/electron tutorials but they only cover dev, none of them seem to go as far as building it and running the finished product.